# QuickBlox Chat Not Available

Tags: quickblox

I'm currently trying to implement the Chat module of Quickblox, but it seems that I can't connect to chat.quickblox.com, I am getting an error during the POST request. Did they change this? Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the connect to chat service with default config file from web chat sample? So aren't changing it.
And show we what response will be from the server?